# Azure Container Name RegEx

Tags: c#, regex, azure-blob-storage

How to validate Azure Container name using regex? I found the following line of code from some other post, but it is not validating the consecutive dashes (-).

```
if (!Regex.IsMatch(containerName, @"^[a-z0-9](([a-z0-9\-[^\-])){1,61}[a-z0-9]$"))
 throw new Exception("Invalid container name);
```

E.g. the following string is considered valid with the above regex pattern:

```
test--test
```

The rules are:

- 3 to 63 Characters;
- Starts With Letter or Number;
- Contains Letters, Numbers, and Dash (`-`);
- Every Dash (`-`) Must Be Immediately Preceded and Followed by a Letter or Number

Comment: This regex contains a user error: I believe this `[a-z0-9\-[^\-]` part is not doing what the author meant to match. What kind of string is it meant to match? What are the requirements?

Comment: - 3 to 63 Characters;
- Starts With Letter or Number;
- Contains Letters, Numbers, and Dash (-);
- Every Dash (-) Must Be Immediately Preceded and Followed by a Letter or Number

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you follow your custom way of solving the issue, you can use

```
^[a-z0-9](?!.*--)[a-z0-9-]{1,61}[a-z0-9]$
```

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/eL5oG2/1)

The `(?!.*--)` lookahead will fail a match if there are 2 consecutive hyphens in the string.

Now, speaking about the [`Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.NameValidator.ValidateContainerName(string containerName)`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-net/blob/master/Lib/Common/NameValidator.cs): the code is just repeating the logic of the regex above *with separate argument exceptions per issue*.

```
private const int ContainerShareQueueTableMinLength = 3;
private const int ContainerShareQueueTableMaxLength = 63;
```

These two lines set the min and max length of the container name and are checked against in the `private static void ValidateShareContainerQueueHelper(string resourceName, string resourceType)` method. The regex used there is

```
private static readonly Regex ShareContainerQueueRegex = 
    new Regex("^[a-z0-9]+(-[a-z0-9]+)*$", NameValidator.RegexOptions);
```

So, this pattern is all you need if you add the length restriction to it:

```
^(?=.{3,63}$)[a-z0-9]+(-[a-z0-9]+)*$
 ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

This regex is a "synonym" of the one at the top of the answer.

**You should use the `NameValidator` approach if you need different *`ArgumentException`s* to signal different issues.** Else, you may use your one-regex solution.

Answer (score 13):

I know it's not exactly what you asked, but rather than rolling your own regex, you can use a method that is built into the storage client library: `Microsoft.Azure.Storage.NameValidator.ValidateContainerName(myContainerName)`

If the name is not valid then this method throws an `ArgumentException`.  As you would guess from the name, this static class contains methods for validating names of queues, tables, blobs, directories and others.

Comment: At the time of writing this comment, the `NameValidator.ValidateBlobName` does not seem to work, while `NameValidator.ValidateContainerName` works fine. So be careful with using the validation methods in the `NameValidator`.

Answer (score 1):

In Powershell, you can do this:

```html
function Test-ContainerNameValidity($ContainerName)
{
    Import-Module -Name AzureRM
    Write-Host "Testing container name against Microsoft's naming rules."
    try {
        [Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.NameValidator]::ValidateContainerName($ContainerName)
        Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green "Container name is valid!"
        return
    }
    catch {
        Write-Host -ForegroundColor Red "Invalid container name. Please check the container name rules: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/naming-and-referencing-containers--blobs--and-metadata#container-names"
        Write-Host -ForegroundColor Red "The script is now exiting."
        exit
    }
}
```