# Azure blob storage regex pattern for user input validation

Tags: regex, azure, powershell, azure-blob-storage, blob

I’ve developed a function in PowerShell (.NET Framework) to retrieve data from any given Azure Blob Storage: so far, so good.

When it comes down to validate users’ input, unfortunately, I cannot rely on external modules or libraries such as the [NameValidator Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.storage.namevalidator?view=azure-dotnet) of Azure SDK for .NET.

Nevertheless, the article [Naming and Referencing Containers, Blobs, and Metadata](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/naming-and-referencing-containers--blobs--and-metadata) goes into the details of naming rules and thus regex patterns might come to the rescue.

For Container Names I’ve came up with this, and it seems to fit:

```
(?=^.{3,63}$)(?!.*--)[^-][a-z0-9-]*[^-]
```

**Container Names**

> A container name must be a valid DNS name, conforming to the following
> naming rules:
>
> - Container names must start or end with a letter or number, and can contain only letters, numbers, and the dash (-) character.
> - Every dash (-) character must be immediately preceded and followed by a letter or number; consecutive dashes are not permitted in
>   container names.
> - All letters in a container name must be lowercase.
> - Container names must be from 3 through 63 characters long.

For **Blob Names** however I’m not able to get around the counting of path segments:

```
(?=^.{1,1024}$)(?<=^|\/)(\S*?)[^\.] (?=\/|$)
```

NB: the Azure Storage emulator has been deprecated and therefor out of scope.

**Blob Names**

> A blob name must conforming to the following naming rules:
>
> - A blob name can contain any combination of characters.
> - A blob name must be at least one character long and cannot be more than 1,024 characters long, for blobs in Azure Storage.
> - The Azure Storage emulator supports blob names up to 256 characters long. For more information, see Use the Azure storage emulator for
>   development and testing.
> - Blob names are case-sensitive.
> - Reserved URL characters must be properly escaped.
> - The number of path segments comprising the blob name cannot exceed 254. A path segment is the string between consecutive delimiter characters (e.g., the forward slash '/') that corresponds to the name
>   of a virtual directory.
> - Note Avoid blob names that end with a dot (.), a forward slash (/), or a sequence or combination of the two. No path segments should end
>   with a dot (.).

> The Blob service is based on a flat storage scheme, not a hierarchical scheme. However, you may specify a character or string delimiter within a blob name to create a virtual hierarchy. For example, the following list shows valid and unique blob names. Notice that a string can be valid as both a blob name and as a virtual directory name in the same container:

```
/a
/a.txt
/a/b
/a/b.txt
```

> You can take advantage of the delimiter character when enumerating blobs.

NB: Just before asking this question, I’ve found this ones that answer what I’ve already solved on my own or use the aforementioned class:

[Azure Container Name RegEx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35130015/azure-container-name-regex)

[How to validate Azure storage blob names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52877707/how-to-validate-azure-storage-blob-names)

By the way, does anybody know which flavor of regex is used by PowerShell?

Comment: Try `^(?!.{1025})(?:/[^/]*[^/.]){1,254}$`, see  https://regex101.com/r/QxF8OS/1

Comment: Hi @WiktorStribiżew ,I've managed to merge my first attempt with your suggestion.

The end result is this:

`^(?=.{1,1024})(?:\/*([^\/]*[^\/\.])){1,254}$`

This way I'm able to limit both length and repetitions while capturing the groups that matched.

Comment: Your regex is wrong.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, why?

Comment: It allows even 100000 chars. [It allows](https://regex101.com/r/abdzEQ/2) `///////a` string, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use

```
^(?!.{1025})/?[^/]*[^/.](?:/[^/]*[^/.]){0,253}$
^(?=.{1,1024}$)/?[^/]*[^/.](?:/[^/]*[^/.]){0,253}$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/abdzEQ/1).

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?=.{1,1024}$)` - the string should contain from 1 to 1024 chars
- `(?!.{1025})` - the string cannot contain more than 1025 chars
- `/?` - an optional `/`
- `[^/]*[^/.]` - zero or more chars other than `/` and then a char other than `/` and `.`
- `(?:/[^/]*[^/.]){0,253}`  - zero to 253 occurrences of `/` followed by zero or more chars other than `/` and then a char other than `/` and `.`
- `$` - end of string.